# How to dynamically repeat-x on a background image of a child, depending on the width of the parent element with CSS/jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, dynamic, background

I have a menu

```
<ul>
<li class="parent"> Dynamic text content 
   <ul> 
       <li class="child"> Dynamic text content1 </li>
       <li class="child"> Dynamic text content2 </li>
   </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

now the width of the li.parent can change depending on the text inside. Let's say that the width of a li.parent is (y) px. Now say the width of li.child is (y+z) px. I want to put a background-image to the li.child as follows: the first (y) px is a specific background image ( so i want to repeat-x for y pixels, to match the width of the parent) and for the next (z) pixels I want another background image to repeat-x.

Can I achieve this through CSS or do I have to use jQuery? any directions would be more than welcome

Comment: Are the widths fixed or variable?

Comment: the width of li.parent is variable. the width of li.child is fixed and bigger than the width of the li.parent

Answer (score 0):

I dont think it is possible with css just like that (but I dont know css3)

But maybe you can add 2 elements inside the li child(one of the size of the li parent) and one of the size of the rest, put the background-image on these elements with repeat-x.

you probably will need javascript to set the width to the first element which should be the same as the li parent

Answer (score 0):

You can append elements with jQuery to the child element, then style them to achieve the effect.

Note: you will need to position the appended `.child-after` elements to match the width of the parent as well.

[This Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2XbMM/85/) should get you on the right path.

jQuery:

```
$('.parent').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var parentWidth = $this.outerWidth();
  var $child = $this.find('.child').eq(0);
  var childWidth = $child.outerWidth();

  $child.append('<span class="child-before"></span>').append('<span class="child-after"></span>');

  $child.find('.child-before').css('width',parentWidth + 'px');    
  $child.find('.child-after').css('width',(childWidth - parentWidth) + 'px');
});
```

CSS:

```
.parent { width:40px; background:#e6e6e6; }
.child {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #efefef;
    top:20px;
}

.child-before,
.child-after {
  display:block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.child-before {
  left: 0;
  height: 70px;
  background-image: url(http://placehold.it/5x70);
  background-repeat: repeat;
}

.child-after {
  left: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-image: url(http://placehold.it/5x40);
  background-repeat: repeat;
}
```